# Unity keeps freezing in while loop having a random function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, random, infinite-loop

I am making a tic tac toe game unity And when its the computer's turn , it selects a random number if the random number is already marked then it generates another random number and checks it again , but its getting stuck in while loop i don't know why.

```
public void checkComputer()
{
    if ( Variab == 0 && whoseTurn == 1)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int rand = Random.Range(0, 8);
            while (markedSpaces[rand] != 1 || markedSpaces[rand] != 2)
            {
                rand = Random.Range(0, 8);
                j++;
            }

            TicTacToeButton(rand);

    }
 }
```

Comment: First thing you can do here is to debug your rand value and markedSpaces[rand] value to see what's going on.
Also if you can give us the whole code so we can understand more what each variable/ array do. Thanks.

Comment: the code inside the while loop does not modify the variables of its break condition. if all marked spaces covered by indices 0..8 are 1 or 2 before you enter the loop, it is not going to halt.

Comment: Other issues aside, note that `(markedSpaces[rand] != 1 || markedSpaces[rand] != 2)` is **always** true!

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions keeps popping up but I wouldn't consider this as a duplicate but it's the-same issue with different solution.

You should **not** use `Random.Range` to determine when to exit a function. This is bound to fail and the result is an infinite loop. As soon as you see something like  `while(Random.Range(...))` in your code, you have to stop and re-evaluate how you are tackling this problem.

In your particular case, the condition in the code below has to be `false` in order for that random number to be considered fine:

```
while (markedSpaces[rand] != 1 || markedSpaces[rand] != 2)
```

---

*Re-write the code and remove the need for a loop that depends on `Random.Range` to exist.*

Create a function that loops over `markedSpaces` and checks if the value of `markedSpaces` is `1` or `2`. If `1` or `2`, add it to a `List` then return that `List`:

```
List<int> GetValidSpacesIndexes()
{
    List<int> markedSpacesIndexes = new List<int>();

    //Loop through the markedSpaces 
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //Get indexes with 1 or 2 values
        if (markedSpaces[i] == 1 || markedSpaces[i] == 2)
        {
            markedSpacesIndexes.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return markedSpacesIndexes;
}
```

Now, in your `checkComputer` function, call the `GetValidSpacesIndexes` function, use `Random.Range(0, validSpacesIndexes.Count)` to obtain the valid index from the value. Use the returned random number to obtain the proper value returned from `markedSpaces` and that's what should be passed to the `TicTacToeButton` function.

```
public void checkComputer()
{
    if (Variab == 0 && whoseTurn == 1)
    {
        //Get Valid indexes
        List<int> validSpacesIndexes = GetValidSpacesIndexes();
        //Geneate Random number within valid Indexes
        int rand = Random.Range(0, validSpacesIndexes.Count);
        //Get the index value
        rand = markedSpaces[rand];

        TicTacToeButton(rand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider how you're doing this. Consider the scenario where the computer has only one space available. Yes, eventually, the computer will guess the right number... But, it'll have to keep generating random numbers until it gets the right one... It's a bit of a waste in terms of resources. Hypothetically, it could generate wrong numbers indefinitely... You could instead, if you want to, create an array of non-played squares and generate a random index within its bounds. This would generate only one random number.

However, as for your current issue, I think it's because you're using an 'or' instead of an 'and'. If the markedspace == 1, then markedspace != 2 is true. If markedspace == 2, then markedspace != 1 is true. If markedspace is any other number, both conditions are true. So you have an infinite loop since no matter what it generates, it'll result in a true value.

Though, if you're saying that 1 and 2 represent players and a blank square is represented by 0, then your condition needs a rewrite... It looks like you're currently trying to picking random numbers as long as the current square is 0... Which is an inverse of what you probably want to do... You should maybe change it to:

```
while (markedSpaces[rand] != 0)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
while (markedSpaces[rand] == 1 || markedSpaces[rand] == 2)
```